# Attempt to create SOAP client in PHP crashes web server

Tags: php, apache, soap

I am trying to create a new soap client with PHP.  My code works just fine on a remote web server, but I am attempting to do it locally on my computer.  I am running Apache 2.2.25 and PHP 5.2.16.

Here is the full error message that Apache is giving before crashing:

```
[Wed Dec 11 21:01:09 2013] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.100.102 for ServerName
[Wed Dec 11 21:01:10 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.25 (Win32) PHP/5.2.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Dec 11 21:01:10 2013] [notice] Server built: Jul 10 2013 01:52:12
[Wed Dec 11 21:01:10 2013] [error] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : Parent: Could not set child process stdout
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.100.102 for ServerName
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.100.102 for ServerName
[Wed Dec 11 21:01:10 2013] [notice] Child 5432: Child process is running
[Wed Dec 11 21:01:10 2013] [crit] (OS 109)The pipe has been ended.  : Child 5432: Unable to retrieve the ready event from the parent
```

I know the new SoapClient syntax is correct because it works perfectly on my a remote web server.

I have the php_soap.dll in the extensions folder and have it loaded in the extensions.

Do I have something configured incorrectly with PHP and Apache?

EDIT:  I figured out the problem.  SSL was not enabled on the Apache server and the SOAP server uses SSL.  Once I added the openssl.dll extension the call worked just fine.

Comment: I had that type of error on centos...Is it what you'r using? the proble is the server confiuration i think...check your httpd.conf

Comment: check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name

Comment: [Please review what an FQDN is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name)

Comment: Ok, thank you Emilio and Ohgodwhy.  I was able to eliminate that error with your advice, but it is still crashing and throwing the "Cannot fine the file specified" and "Unable to retrive ready event..." erors.